# Can't connect to PostgreSQL db from docker executor (gitlab ci/cd)

Tags: python, postgresql, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried the way explained in [official gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html#use-postgresql-with-the-docker-executor), configured database on the host and tried to connect with `DB_HOST=postgres`. But `psycopg` throws error: `(psycopg.OperationalError) connection is bad: Name or service not known`. My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image: python:3.11

default:
  services:
    - postgres:15.1

before_script:
  - python3.11 --version
  - pip3.11 --version
  - echo "hello world"

build-python:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "this is test job"
    - cd backend
    - pip3.11 install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
    - pip3.11 install -r requirements.txt
    - echo "ended building python test job"
    - alembic revision --autogenerate -m "migrating"
    - alembic upgrade head
```

Alembic.ini file from where I'm trying to access db:

```ini
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = migrations

prepend_sys_path = .

version_path_separator = os  # Use os.pathsep. Default configuration used for new projects.


sqlalchemy.url = driver://user:pass@localhost/dbname


[post_write_hooks]

[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

`sqlalchemy.url` is defined in `env.py`

```py
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', DATABASE_URL)
```

The `DATABASE_URL`:

```py
DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql+psycopg://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'
```

What did I miss to do? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have little experience with GitLab but two things stand out. First, put all the commands into a _single_ script (don’t use `-`) to ensure all commands run in the same shell. Second, where’s the [Alembic config](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file) which configures the connection to the db?

Comment: @Jens I edited the question and attached alembic.ini

Comment: What are the `DB_xxx` environment variables? You ought to be able to connect to `localhost:5432`. Also, which PG driver do you use, v2 or v3? I usually use `postgresql+psycopg2`.

Also, migrations should be part of the source, not generated in CI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the PostgreSQL container fails to start because it misses the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` mandatory environement variable. See [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for this image, section Environment Variables. One way to troubleshoot would be to print the logs of the PostgreSQL container using

```yaml
variables:
  CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: 'true'
```

It will show the logs of the PostgreSQL container on your job's logs.

If the PostgreSQL container starts properly, then you should be able to reach it using the `postgres` hostname, as according to [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services) :

> The default aliases for the service’s hostname are created from its
> image name following these rules:
>
> - Everything after the colon (:) is stripped.
> - Slash (/) is replaced with double underscores (__) and the primary alias is created.
> - Slash (/) is replaced with a single dash (-) and the secondary alias is created (requires GitLab Runner v1.1.0 or later).